# How do i obtain the setMultiChoiceItems items from my AlertDialog?

Tags: android

I'm using the following code from the apidemos..

```
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialogSamples.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_popup_reminder)
            .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_multi_choice)
            .setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.select_dialog_items3,
                    new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false, false, false},
                    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton,
                                boolean isChecked) {

                            /* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */
                        }
                    })
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    /* User clicked No so do some stuff */
                }
            })
           .create();
```

Under `/* User clicked Yes so do some stuff */`, i'm not fed the isChecked variable.. however, I am given isChecked in the `/* User clicked on a check box do some stuff */` section.. Obviously i don't want to update my SharedPrefs on checkbox click, in case the user hits cancel..

So how do I get the checkboxs and values on the `setPositiveButton` onClick ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a reference to `byte[]` in `setMultiChoiceItems()`.

```
    final boolean[] booleans = {false, true, false, true, false, false, false};
```

Then check the value of `booleans` inside `setPositiveButton()`.

If you need to pass this `AlertDialog` around, then extend `AlertDialog` and have create a field `boolean` as described in 1.

Comment: Can anyone else confirm this? It's not clear from the documentation that this is the behaviour, and when I tested on Android 2.2 the values in the array didn't change after checking the boxes.

Comment: The values are not changed on Android 5.1 too.

Answer (score 5):

use getListView() of AlertDialog class. and fetch the listView.
i.e when you call .create() at the end this will fetch you a new AlertDialog.

Then use one of the following methods:

```
 1. getCheckItemPositions:SparseBooleanArray
 2. getCheckedItemIds:long[]
```

I can provide you with demo code. Give me 10-15 mins.

Comment: Try something along the lines of: `((AlertDialog) aDialogue).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions()`.

Comment: getCheckItemPositions:SparseBooleanArray worked perfect thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get checked items when setMultiChoiceItems is used in AlertDialog.Builder,
you must create DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener with even empty onClick.
Only on this condition checkedItems in second params will be used and updated internally in AlertController and reflect checked items on exit (i.e. in setPositiveButton callback)

Check this AlertController code:

```
...    
} else if (mOnCheckboxClickListener != null) {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                if (mCheckedItems != null) {
                    mCheckedItems[position] = listView.isItemChecked(position);
                }
                mOnCheckboxClickListener.onClick(
                        dialog.mDialogInterface, position, listView.isItemChecked(position));
            }
        });
    }
...
```