# Checkbox Dialog selecting programmatically

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically select my check boxes within my checkbox dialog code I have set up.

How would I be able to programmatically toggle my checkboxes from my onClick method down below.

If anyone could take a look at my code so far, and give me some guidance, that would be great.

Code:

```
            AlertDialog dialog;

        final CharSequence[] items = { "All listings", "Buy it now",
                "Auction", "Nearest first" };

        final ArrayList<Integer> seletedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        final SharedPreferences shfObject = getActivity()
                .getSharedPreferences("NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor shfEditorObject = shfObject.edit();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Filter");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            final int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {





                        }
                    }
                })
                // Set the action buttons
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {





                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // Your code when user clicked on Cancel

                            }
                        });

        dialog = builder.create();// AlertDialog dialog; create like this
                                    // outside onClick
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Are you not aware of 'checkBox.setChecked(true);' or I am not getting your question correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `null` in your second parameter you gotta pass `new boolean[]{false, true, false, true, false}` (depending on your checkboxes). It will select the checkboxex you wish to .

[Referenced Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162756/how-do-i-obtain-the-setmultichoiceitems-items-from-my-alertdialog)

[How do i obtain the setMultiChoiceItems items from my AlertDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162756/how-do-i-obtain-the-setmultichoiceitems-items-from-my-alertdialog)